# Google Geochart: Improper colour code for the disputed for area

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I am using Google Geochart API for implementing state wise Report for Indian Political Map. I used the following code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});
var ivalue = new Array();

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-AP',f:'Andhra Pradesh'}, 5,'5']]);
ivalue['IN-AP'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andhra_Pradesh';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-AR',f:'Arunachal Pradesh'},4,'4']]);
ivalue['IN-AR'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arunachal_Pradesh';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-AS',f:'Assam'},2,'2']]);
ivalue['IN-AS'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assam';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-BR',f:'Bihar'},3,'3']]);
ivalue['IN-BR'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihar';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-CT',f:'Chhattisgarh'},4,'4']]);
ivalue['IN-CT'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhattisgarh';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-GA',f:'Goa'},5,'5']]);
ivalue['IN-GA'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-GJ',f:'Gujarat'},6,'6']]);
ivalue['IN-GJ'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarat';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-HR',f:'Haryana'},7,'7']]);
ivalue['IN-HR'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haryana';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-HP',f:'Himachal Pradesh'},7,'3']]);
ivalue['IN-HP'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himachal_Pradesh';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-JK',f:'Jammu and Kashmir'},3,'3']]);
ivalue['IN-JK'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jammu_and_Kashmir';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-JH',f:'Jharkhand'},4,'4']]);
ivalue['IN-JH'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jharkhand';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-KA',f:'Karnataka'},8,'8']]);
ivalue['IN-KA'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnataka';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-KL',f:'Kerala'},7,'7']]);
ivalue['IN-KL'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerala';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-MP',f:'Madhya Pradesh'},8,'8']]);
ivalue['IN-MP'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhya_Pradesh';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-MH',f:'Maharashtra'},9,'9']]);
ivalue['IN-MH'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharashtra';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-MN',f:'Manipur'},7,'7']]);
ivalue['IN-MN'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manipur';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-ML',f:'Meghalaya'},4,'4']]);
ivalue['IN-ML'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meghalaya';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-MZ',f:'Mizoram'},3,'3']]);
ivalue['IN-MZ'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizoram';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-NL',f:'Nagaland'},2,'2']]);
ivalue['IN-NL'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagaland';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-OR',f:'Orissa'},4,'4']]);
ivalue['IN-OR'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orissa';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-PB',f:'Punjab'},5,'5']]);
ivalue['IN-PB'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punjab';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-RJ',f:'Rajasthan'},7,'7']]);
ivalue['IN-RJ'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajasthan';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-SK',f:'Sikkim'},4,'4']]);
ivalue['IN-SK'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikkim';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-TN',f:'Tamil Nadu'},8,'8']]);
ivalue['IN-TN'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_Nadu';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-TR',f:'Tripura'},3,'3']]);
ivalue['IN-TR'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripura';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-UT',f:'Uttarakhand'},4,'4']]);
ivalue['IN-UT'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttarakhand';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-UP',f:'Uttar Pradesh'},8,'8']]);
ivalue['IN-UP'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttar_Pradesh';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-WB',f:'West Bengal'},7,'7']]);
ivalue['IN-WB'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Bengal';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-AN',f:'Andaman and Nicobar Islands'},2,'2']]);
ivalue['IN-AN'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andaman_and_Nicobar_Islands';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-CH',f:'Chandigarh'},6,'6']]);
ivalue['IN-CH'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandigarh';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-DN',f:'Dadra and Nagar Haveli'},4,'4']]);
ivalue['IN-DN'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadra_and_Nagar_Haveli';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-DD',f:'Daman and Diu'},2,'2']]);
ivalue['IN-DD'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daman_and_Diu';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-DL',f:'Delhi'},10,'10']]);
ivalue['IN-DL'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delhi';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-LD',f:'Lakshadweep'},1,'1']]);
ivalue['IN-LD'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshadweep';

data.addRows([[{v:'IN-PY',f:'Puducherry (Pondicherry)'},6,'6']]);
ivalue['IN-PY'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puducherry';

var options = {
backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },
colorAxis: {colors: ['yellow','orange', 'red']},
backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 }, 
datalessRegionColor: '#FFFFFF',
displayMode: 'regions', 
enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
resolution: 'provinces',
sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
region:'IN',
keepAspectRatio: true,
width:800,
height:500,
tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus'}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization')); 
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
var selection = chart.getSelection();
if (selection.length == 1) {
var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
var selectedRegion = data.getValue(selectedRow, 0);
if(ivalue[selectedRegion] != '') { window.open(ivalue[selectedRegion]);  }
}
});
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

In this, top most state ie. Jammu and Kashmir is disputed. Is there is any way I can implement any one of the following: 
 1. Either I can remove the disputed area and show the whole state as it is, with proper colour. 
 2. Or any how, show the disputed state's having same colour for disputed and undisputed area.

Can we also have more that one "region" in options with "resolution: 'provinces' "?

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer and I confess I don't know too much about this aspect of google.maps but it says [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes) that :

> The inner workings of map types within the Maps API is an advanced
>   topic. Most developers can simply use the basic map types noted
>   below. However, you can also define your own map tiles using custom
>   map types or modify the presentation of existing map types using
>   Styled Maps. When providing custom map types, you will need to
>   understand how to modify the map's Map Type Registry.

With some effort, this should provide a mechanism by which you can offer your own recolored map tiles for the disputed region.

Answer (score 4):

i was searching for solution, and found that we can pass parameter as "IN" in domain options, which will consider Kashmir as Indian state instead of listing as disputed, check for all options in following link

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: @AqibMapari Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The link from the answer is dead though. Here's the documentation link, search for "domain" : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options

Answer (score 0):

The underlying SVG for that map shows the territory as disputed, and short of editing the SVG itself you cannot change them. Here are the relevant lines for Jammu and Kashmir in Pakistan:

```
<path d="M309.80792933629334,18.989110296063618L312.62808795206297,22.726320565659634L318.8362126083018,25.16463114909045L322.88492641920095,24.446213181078875L321.8625826161618,21.835482285325142L316.19903029818965,21.424547207622577L313.5211865868203,19.382803342533922L312.8444646944677,15.12689530003403L305.6009264990715,11.194275343138958L300.6533052818071,6.069081559344707L302.39738895716204,12.655537490074323L300.87113421711376,15.882671002382095L302.96229199605716,16.411426626838498L303.9512353623492,19.871327560781815L309.88634775300363,18.911521155518564Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0)">
<path d="M352.86980546060823,44.62370023065002L352.8785186180206,43.459863122471255L356.59758464015573,43.43831058343074L357.38612538596567,40.084735508753326L360.68986423811594,39.4554013687749L363.73656494660463,28.12020266948963L365.6955731714622,26.554051499224865L364.9070324256523,25.10715771164957L362.56754966045906,24.223503610995472L360.38199934288275,26.901765795742225L359.568771317738,23.74216357242775L355.29061102831594,23.094150565281495L353.37081201181365,18.535070140280627L352.16258751731283,19.37418...61059265807575,30.294135440692685L333.46705609639645,34.82016863916499L334.505374021358,40.82757968767728L345.62626726521205,45.57488562029698L343.98383709300026,49.103754679169384L340.0876035368157,50.47449616213537L342.8090130352466,61.802510681740465L344.1900484850904,62.31258743902904L343.71808579192606,58.345483419669286L346.3828597671772,58.19461564638694L343.6483805326281,51.75471698113179L350.9195103931631,51.74178545770757L353.8834361062351,47.64823987597818L352.81897870903674,44.681173668090736Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0)">
```

The two paths are for the northwest, and east portion (two separate shapes).

Here are the relevant lines for Jammu and Kashmir in India:

```
<path d="M349.0708688288608,76.60192082277737L351.06472968336755,77.21401293152348L353.21397517839284,73.89923242711829L349.8768358894954,68.99962188527996L351.03713801822863,65.88599841191811L346.62247159601435,65.58713653722538L342.6797678669645,61.687563806858705L340.9632758567483,58.30668884939667L341.3205153106512,51.78201686391614L340.04839432846063,51.111014481793575L345.84409620051866,46.20709343214726L340.8471004245848,42.639429803001754L334.505374021358,40.82757968767728L333.46705609639645,34.82016863916...24963L294.35369247273957,81.03599652134461L300.39191055943917,75.65648277687451L298.7596457375414,70.17351684501048L300.878395181624,70.74106703973978L309.4463333036843,65.00952849094406L321.2439484398911,71.4250009452865L326.4979823594866,68.71656520588343L330.6817501102758,75.89930805006198L335.88640947120206,73.01557832646392L334.9221533842447,78.0991038681132L341.2798539093941,74.2167731689795L341.8592788773095,77.91375203236635L344.60247126927095,80.35206261579755L349.0563468998405,76.64646273679408Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_4)">
```

Here is the path for Arunachal and Pradesh:

Basically, these shapes are given a "disputed territories" fill. To eliminate that fill entirely, you can edit the SVG to remove the above paths with that fill, or you can remove the definitions for those fills. Removing the shape is probably the more appropriate way to do it, but removing the definitions is much quicker and easier (because they are at the top, and earlier to find and remove if you do want to change something later). Here are the definitions:

- ID_0 controls the grey lines in Pakistan
- ID_1 controls the grey lines in India (Arunachal and Pradesh)
- ID_3 controls the grey lines in India (Jammu and Kashmir)

You can search for the id using jquery or the like, and just delete them. Here is what the map looks like initially:

[image: Default Map]

This is what the map looks like if you remove ID 1 and 3 (keeping the disputed part of Kashmir in Pakistan in grey):

[image: Big India]

This is what the map looks like if you remove ID 0, 1, and 3 (removing all diagonal lines marking disputed territories):

[image: Undisputed India]

Point is, you have to edit the SVG.

**Disclaimer: The above is given as examples of how to technically achieve the desired results without taking any stance on disputed territories either in the case above or otherwise. This is technical help, not indicative of any political views.**